# How to import CSV files into MariaDB in a secure and performant way?

Tags: mariadb, php, import, csv

We have a PHP based web application that allows the upload of CSV files. These CSV files with up to 2.5 million rows are to be imported into a table in a MariaDB. How can we make this import secure and performant at the same time?

1. A quick solution would be to give the database user the `FILE` privilege so that he can read in the file using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. However, this is risky, as other databases are present in the daemon.
2. It would be safer to parse the CSV file in PHP and process it as single or grouped `INSERT INTO` commands. However, this is slow and time-consuming.

What would be the best practice here? Using the underlying operating system and its bash would also be an option. Thank you!

Comment: *However, this is risky, as other databases are present in the daemon.* ?? Why do you think so?

Comment: @Akina - I think there is nothing to prevent a different DB user from accessing the same infile via a similar `LOAD DATA` command.

Comment: (I disagree with the vote to Close.  Sure "secure" and "performant" sound like 2 different questions.  But the question is about how to achieve _both at the same time_.

Comment: @Akina I got this information from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552253/17240442). Basically, it boils down to this one sentence: A user who has the FILE privilege can read any file on the server host that is either world-readable or readable by the MySQL server.

Comment: *Basically, it boils down to this one sentence* Never trust quotes. Always refer to original text. Study the most last paragraph of this privilege description..

Comment: @Akina Thanks for clarifying. I will have another look at the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/#load-data-local-infile) is another option that avoid the need for `FILE` privileges however it does requires a specific option on the connection. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638090/load-data-local-infile-forbidden-in-php#17430025).

If its loading into a new table 10.7+ will have [performance benefits](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-innodb-bulk-insert/) if both `foreign_key_checks=0` and `unique_checks=0` are set for the session.

[ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TABLE ... TO PARTITION](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-convert-partition/) is a way to move a new table into a partition if your data is partition orientated.

On the server, ensure you have a sufficient [innodb_log_file_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size) to cover the size of the imports and [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size) otherwise the import may be stalled as the server flushes contents/frees up other pool elements.